# Windows 7 is taking too long to load

Tags: windows-7, boot, bootloader

When I turn on my computer (Windows 7) the operating system is loading for 10 minutes.

The following screen is displayed for the first 9 minutes:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trying to boot from a network source, just go to your BOIS settings and change boot order, put booting from HDD before NIC then save your settings and you should be ready to go.

**Steps to take:**

1- Restart your computer.

2- while first booting and when the motherboard logo appears, look for BIOS setup key (it will be shown in the corner, usually *F12*,*F11* or something like that).

3- After entering the BIOS setup, go to boot ordering options (depends on the motherboard brand, but this is very easy to find).

4- The normal boot flow order will be something like this: (Editing instructions for keyboard keys to use will be shown on the right or down edge of the screen)

```
a) CD/DVD (in the old days this used to be the first option, now we boot from pen drives).
b) HDD
c) Other options like network boot (NIC), or even disable it, it's safer.
```

5- Choose *Save and reboot* option (or something similar).

6- Enjoy your normal boot flow ;)

**Why this happened ?**

As the pictures shoes, the motherboard is running DHCP to try and find an IP address then try to find a booting network resource on the local network and boot an operating system from, this is because of the boot order we wrote about,

Comment: Can you expand on your answer, so it's useful to others too?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like PXE boot, if you press escape during this it should continue to boot.

Otherwise you can go in to your CMOS settings and disable this as a boot option.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer, so it's useful to others too?